# Camera orientation not changing Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-camera

For my application I am using android native camera and previewing the image using surface view. in my case everything is working except the camera orientation. When I open the camera by setting  screenOrientation="landscape on manifest file I am getting the preview without any problem in landscape mode. But I need to take image in portrait mode, for this I changed my manifest like  android:screenOrientation="portrait"  and change my code like mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90), params.set("orientation", "landscape"),params.set("rotation", 90), but still I am getting 90 degree rotated image. 
And my code is

```
  public void setupCamera(int width, int height) {
    Log.i(TAG, "setupCamera");
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
            List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            List<Camera.Size> imgsize=params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
            mFrameWidth = width;
            mFrameHeight = height;

           // mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            params.set("orientation", "landscape");
             params.set("rotation", 90);
            // selecting optimal camera preview size
            {
                int  minDiff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                    if (Math.abs(size.height - height) < minDiff) {
                        mFrameWidth = size.width;
                        mFrameHeight = size.height;
                        minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - height);
                    }
                }
            }

            params.setPreviewSize(getFrameWidth(), getFrameHeight());




            List<String> FocusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
            if (FocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO))
            {
                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
            }            

            mCamera.setParameters(params);



            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Micromax A 52 model...
Any one please help.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application runs on v2.2 or above you can rotate camera orientation to portrait using `camera.setDisplayOrientation(90)`.

For others:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

//After opening camera - call via reflection
Method rotateMethod = android.hardware.Camera.class.getMethod("setDisplayOrientation", int.class);
rotateMethod.invoke(mCamera, 90);
```

for more details please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504605/camera-is-wrong-unless-keyboard-is-open/5504651#5504651) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259299/force-a-camera-to-always-open-in-portrait-mode-in-android) 
 Hope this will be helpful

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your reply.....I tried the above but still the image is rotated...

Comment: if you used this code then now  i think you should remove all the code which is related to rotation.

Comment: camera.setDisplayOrientation(90)
this worked for Android ICS and Above, but not for 2.3.6,
In the doc it says  "'setDisplayOrientation()' is for Android 14 and up"
hope you will change the answer