# Android camera is in landscape but used in portrait mode

Tags: android, camera

I hold my phone in "portrait mode" but the `cameraPreview` is in mode landscape (i.e. I see something rotated by 90 degrees). When I turned the phone to hold it in "landscape mode" the preview is fine and is in "landscape mode", the image is not rotated.
I do not have access to `Camera.setDisplayOrientation(int)`, so I can't use the method explained [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29).

I've tried:

```
Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {   
        p.set("orientation", "portrait");
        p.set("rotation",90);
    }
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {                               
        p.set("orientation", "landscape");          
        p.set("rotation", 90);
    }
```

Comment: Insted of down voting you could read and help.

Comment: Alternatively, you could explain [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? It generally works better than a generic "how do I do X?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I've solve the problem
In the "surfaceCreated" method do

```
    Method rotateMethod;
    rotateMethod = android.hardware.Camera.class.getMethod("setDisplayOrientation", int.class);
    rotateMethod.invoke(camera, 90);
```

just after

```
camera = Camera.open();
```

(cf: [Camera is wrong unless keyboard is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504605/camera-is-wrong-unless-keyboard-is-open/5504651#5504651))

Comment: This fixed the orientation to Portrait mode. How can I change from Portrait to Landscape when orientation is changed ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the camera's display orientation by using:

```
Camera camera;
...
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

Put it in the surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) method. This worked for me when I had a similar problem.

Comment: I do not have the method setDisplayOrientation, as said. Probably because I work with an API before level 8

Comment: Do you have acces to:
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
parameters.set("orientation", "portrait"); // or landscape, you might wanna try both...
parameters.setRotation(90);
camera.setParameters(parameters); ?

This might work as well.

Comment: Tried too, did not change anything :/

Comment: Have you tried it with both orientations?
params.set("orientation" , "landscape") and params.set("orientation" , "portrait")? You should play with these a little.

Comment: Yes, I've tried both of them but it is still the same. Maybe I'm not writing it in the right place? (I write it in surfaceCreated)

Comment: i m also using this approach. It showing camera preview in portrait i.e. fine, but when i am saving this image in sdcard it is saving in landscape. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

add code in AndroidManifest.xml Activity in your workspace project.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```