# Default Camera Orientation for Android

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I am working on an Android application in which I want to set the orientation for my default Camera to be Portrait. My code is given below, but it is not working.

```
if(item==0){
    mPicUri = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(10101));
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mPicUri);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION,
    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_PIC_CAMERA);
}
```

Comment: your resultant image is in landscape or camera view itself ?

Comment: Other report problems with the Intent approach to force Cam Preview into Portrait. See this answer for a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504605/camera-is-wrong-unless-keyboard-is-open/5504651#5504651

Comment: This question needs more of a problem description than "not working", it seems it is missing a [mcve].