# How can I get a camera preview on a surfaceholder in portrait mode?

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

I'm using the following custom SurfaceView for some AR task. I set `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` for my activity in the AndroidManifest, but the image is rotated by 90 deg with weird aspect ratio. I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S...

Anybody can help?

```
public class CustomCameraView extends SurfaceView
{
    Camera camera;
    SurfaceHolder previewHolder;

    SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceHolderListener = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int w, int h)
        {
            Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setPreviewSize( 800, 480);
            params.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.startPreview();
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0)
        {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
        }
    };

    public CustomCameraView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        previewHolder = this.getHolder();
        previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceHolderListener);
    }

    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    public void closeCamera()
    {
        if(camera != null)
            camera.release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camera application on many devices has a defect where it will only properly display in landscape mode, locking the display to landscape mode fixes this but has other problems (like forcing you to manage the layout)

[Stackflow Discussion 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691424/using-camera-in-portrait-orientation)

[Stackflow Discussion 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543059/android-camera-in-portrait-on-surfaceview)

Etc ...

Some devices+sdk versions work in portrait as per the doc's and samples around the web, some don't I have just come to expect they won't and implemented the landscape only route, a bit of a pain but it works.