# android camera portrait orientation

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, landscape-portrait

I am using camera in my app. I am just using `intent` to start camera

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 101);
```

The captured image automatically comes in `landscape view`. How do i make `camera` to capture images in `portrait view`

Comment: i am facing the same issue, please tell me how do you solved this....

Comment: @SivaK Instead of using default camera app, i created my own camera view to capture images

Comment: Seshu Vinay - thanks for your reply, is there any sample code or blog for creating our own camera view

Comment: There's an answer below which gives some sample code

Comment: Thanks - just now i gone through the FoodSpotting app, it uses the default camera, capturing photo in portrait and when the photo gets retrieved its in same portrait mode.... i will search for it...thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If device has `v2.2` or above you can rotate camera orientation to portrait using `camera.setDisplayOrientation(90)`. In devices below to v2.2 the camera will only display in landscape orientation and thus image will come in landscape. Check these posts [Using Camera in Portrait Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691424/using-camera-in-portrait-orientation), [Camera is wrong unless keyboard is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504605/camera-is-wrong-unless-keyboard-is-open/5504651#5504651).

Comment: I don't think this will work without actually overriding the camera class - calling an intent won't be enough here

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
        Parameters param = mCamera.getParameters();

        switch(mDisplay.getRotation()){
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                Log.d("Rotation_0", "whatever");
            }
            else{
                Log.d("Rotation_0", "whatever");
                param.setRotation(90);
                mCamera.setParameters(param);
            }
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
                Log.d("Rotation_0", "whatever");
            }
            else{
                Log.d("Rotation_90", "whatever");
                param.setRotation(0);
                mCamera.setParameters(param);
            }
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, this code is suitable for all types of orientation that are supported in android camera application[Portrait mode] too.

```
int rotation = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
int degrees = 0;

switch (rotation) {

    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
        degrees = 0;
        break;

    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
        degrees = 90;
        break;

    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        degrees = 180;
        break;

    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
        degrees = 270;
        break;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim Castelijns